# Delete SharePoint Calendar Overlay

Tags: 2010, powershell, calendar, overlay

I am trying to delete the calendar overlay but I am not able to delete it.

The overlay is from the other site collection, but that site collection is deleted.

When I try to delete the overlay, it is throwing this error:

> File Not Found

Can anyone suggest me PowerShell command to remove the overlay from the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to delete the overlay view of your calendar list. Please check if below powershell code helps you:

```
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$List = $SPWeb.Lists["CalendarName"]
$View = $List.Views["OverlayViewName"]
$List.Views.Delete($View.ID)
$List.Update()
$SPWeb.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()
```